# Should I ask for a raise I know I won't get?

Tags: raise

Recently, I've been told (both verbally and in writing) by the managing director of our small nonprofit* that he's really impressed with how much extra responsibility I've been taking on of my own accord. These responsibilities include project management, which is definitely outside my job description.

I feel like this extra work, and his acknowledgement of it, might mean I should ask for a raise. However, I also know that the organisation is in dire financial straits and that it can't afford to give me a raise (Not to mention that the leftist in me would like to negotiate as a team with my colleagues).

So, would I gain any future advantage by officially making a request now while it's fresh in the manager's mind?

*It's a CIC with fewer then 10 employees

Comment: Down-voters, how can I improve this question?

Comment: Does https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189720/asking-a-big-raise-from-employer-whose-company-is-in-serious-trouble answer your question?

Comment: What's your goal and what is the desired outcome of the ask?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking a BIG raise from employer whose company is in serious trouble](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189720/asking-a-big-raise-from-employer-whose-company-is-in-serious-trouble)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes you should.**

Asking for the raise, assuming you can justify it, cement's in the mind of your boss and the company the fact that you *deserve* a raise. Even if you are sure that the company can't afford it, it's better to have them aware that you deserve one. One day the company will be in a position to afford raises<sup>1</sup>, and you are in a much better position when that happens if your boss is thinking "We said RichardJ deserved a raise last year but couldn't afford it - let's make sure he gets one now we can".

Of course you also need to be reasonable and understanding when you are told "we would love to give you a raise, but the company can't afford it now".

Notes:

1. Or everybody is looking for a new job